# change select option by javascript

Tags: javascript

i have problem in javascript

i make carwebsite

i need to achieve functionality as per the image
[image]

when I choose company in "make" select box,

it shows me all classes. Then I need to choose a "class" from second dropdown and it should show me all Models

now i get one code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
          $('.car').change(function()
          {           getcar = $(this).val();
           //console.log(getcar);
              $('.subcar').hide();
            $('.'+getcar).show();
             });        });
            // end DOM
                </script>
```

this is select (make)

```
  <select name="car" class="car">
  <option value="0" SELECTED="SELECTED">--Choose--</option>
 <option value="Acura">Acura</option>
<option value="Alfa_Romeo">Alfa Romeo</option>
<option value="Aston_Martin">Aston Martin</option>
<option value="Audi">Audi</option>
<option value="Bentley">Bentley</option>
<option value="BMW">BMW</option>
<option value="Buick">Buick</option>
<option value="Cadillac">Cadillac</option>
<option value="Can_Am">Can Am</option>
<option value="Chery">Chery</option>
<option value="Chevrolet">Chevrolet</option>
<option value="Chrysler">Chrysler</option>
<option value="Citroen">Citroen</option>
<option value="Daihatsu">Daihatsu</option>
<option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
<option value="Ducati">Ducati</option>
<option value="Ferrari">Ferrari</option>
<option value="Fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="Ford">Ford</option>
<option value="GMC">GMC</option>
</select>
```

this is select (class)

```
<select name="branch_name" class="subcar Acura" style="display:none;">
<option value="0" SELECTED="SELECTED" DISABLED="DISABLED">- None -</option>
<option value="CL">CL</option>
<option value="CSX">CSX</option>
<option value="EL">EL</option>
<option value="ILX">ILX</option>
<option value="ZDX">ZDX</option></select>


<select name="branch_name" class="subcar Alfa_Romeo" style="display:none;">
<option value="0" SELECTED="SELECTED" DISABLED="DISABLED">- None -</option>
<option value="101">101</option>
<option value="156">156</option>
<option value="156CROSSWAGON">156CROSSWAGON</option>
<option value="Spider">Spider</option>
 </select>


<select name="branch_name" class="subcar Aston_Martin" style="display:none;">
<option value="0" SELECTED="SELECTED" DISABLED="DISABLED">- None -</option>
<option value="DB9">DB9</option>
<option value="Healey">Healey</option>
<option value="Vantage">Vantage</option>
 </select>
```

how can i make third select

???

Comment: Your JS code looks for an element with class "car" but in your example there is no such element. Please be more specific on your question

Comment: change this line `<select name="country" class="country">` as `<select name="country" class="car">`

Comment: sorry its my wrong now i edit its work ok but i need add third select how ??that what i need